# How to convert simple MySQL query to WordPress meta query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress meta query as I mentioned below, I want to filter these posts by another query from another table.

```
$meta_query_part['relation']     =   'AND';
$country_array =array();
$country_array['key']        =   'property_country';
$country_array['value']      =   $search_string;
$country_array['type']       =   'CHAR';
$country_array['compare']    =   'LIKE'; 
$meta_query_part[]                =   $country_array;

$country_array =array();
$country_array['key']        =   'property_county';
$country_array['value']      =   $search_string;
$country_array['type']       =   'CHAR';
$country_array['compare']    =   'LIKE'; 
$meta_query_part[]           =   $country_array;

$country_array =array();
$country_array['key']        =   'property_state';
$country_array['value']      =   $search_string;
$country_array['type']       =   'CHAR';
$country_array['compare']    =   'LIKE'; 
$meta_query_part[]           =   $country_array;
$meta_query[]=$meta_query_part;

$args = array(
'cache_results'           =>    false,
'update_post_meta_cache'  =>    false,
'update_post_term_cache'  =>    false,
'post_type'               =>    'estate_property',
'post_status'             =>    'publish',
'posts_per_page'          =>    -1,
'meta_key'                =>    'prop_featured',
'orderby'                 =>    'meta_value',
'order'                   =>    'DESC',
'meta_query'              =>    $meta_query,
);

$prop_selection =   new WP_Query($args);
```

Now below is another query that filter posts by price range

```
SELECT post_id FROM `wp_prop_area_availability` WHERE price BETWEEN 34 AND 119
```

[table to filter posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzEbb.png)
How can I convert mysql query to wordpress meta query, or in another words i have results from wordpress meta query and I want to filter these result by price range and this price range is coming from another table.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to filter out

Comment: @SudharshanNair there are lots of $meta_query[] filters, I mentioned only some of them So I have to tied up with wordpress, But one filter from custom table.

Comment: You should be able to use a `JOIN`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Getting_the_final_SQL